# Taylor series for sin(x) centered at pi

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I haven't been able to figure this problem out.

For the Taylor series I got: $$\sin{x}-0 = 0 - (x - \pi ) + 0+ \frac{1}{6} (x-\pi)^3 + 0 - \frac{1}{120} (x-\pi)^5 + o (x^5)
$$

For the series in sigma form I made it: $$ (-1)^n \frac{(x-\pi)^n}{n!}
$$

However, this is incorrect, because I assume the sign is incorrect, but I can't figure out how to make this form right.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your closed form is not correct. See you have only odd powers in expanded form.

Comment: Oh yes!  Welcome to MSE indeed!  Here is the fancy schmancy [MathJax Handbook](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) you might want to bookmark for future reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to take the Taylor series of $\sin(x)$ at $x=\pi$.  This is equivalent to taking the Taylor series of $\sin(x+\pi)$ at $x=0$.

$$\sin(x+\pi)=-\sin(x)=-\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

> $$\sin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(x-\pi)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

Comment: Can you please explain the transition from the first row to the second row?